# inAppSettingsKit Hide Child Pane

Tags: ios, inappsettingskit

I can successfully hide menu items using

```
self.hiddenKeys = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"key1",nil];
```

How can I dynamically hide a child pane sub menu ? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way. Just use the key of the `PSChildPaneSpecifier` dictionary in the parent. If you want to animate the change, there's `-setHiddenKeys:animated:`.

Comment: Sorry about the long delay in marking this correct. The issue was that the PLIST does not suggest key when you push the + for the menu item, If you use a brute force method to add this it works great.